# Session variables + auth in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, session-variables, authentication

Does auth store any variables in the session (e.g. username, other user model properties)? If so, how do I access them? If not, how would I place those variables into the session? In the User controller login function? Thanks, I'm a noob at cakephp

Answer (score 5):

After the user is logged in successfully, all his information will be available in the session..

the best way (CakePHP) to get the user's information from the session is:

```
$this->Auth->user();
```

you should call this from your controller..
it will give you all the user's information,
if you need a specific information (e.g. `username`):

```
$this->Auth->user ( 'username' );
```

and if you want to access the session from a view, you can use:

```
$session->read ( 'Auth.User' );
```

or again (for `username`):

```
$session->read ( 'Auth.User.username' );
```

hope this helps..

good luck with your development..

Comment: That helps me quite a lot actually, thanks. The only problem/question that remains for me is that I feel like this is a massive waste of resources! For example when I log in with Cake on my custom users table, it stores the entire record in session ... including weird fields that aren't really useful to have in a session. Can this be limited somehow?

Comment: How many users do you have? Millions? If it's less than millions, then don't worry about it for now, optimize later :)

Comment: I replied 2 years ago lol. Good advice anyways for newbie CakePHP coders